# Linq2XSD - Looking for articles, tutorials and experiences of

Tags: xml, xsd, linq-to-xsd

Only just found out about this.

Does anyone have any links to some good sites talking about this?
Its features, bugs, limitations.

(obviously I have searched, so am looking for info that wont be on page 1 of Google :D )